# Automatically add appropriate prefix to Quantity

Tags: output-formatting, units

Is there a function that automatically adds the appropriate prefix to a `Quantity` object?

For example, I would like a function

```
quantityWithAppropriatePrefix[Quantity[0.000001,"Meter"]]
```

that would yield

> ```
> Quantity[1,"Micrometers"]
> ```

For some units this hack works:

```
UnitConvert[UnitConvert[0.00001,"Meter"],"Imperial"],"SI"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[10., "Micrometers"]
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITED to include [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)'s replacement for `Switch`
EDITED to cover additional cases

Roll your own:

```
quantityWithAppropriatePrefix[quant_Quantity] := 
  Fold[UnitConvert[#1, #2] &, quant,
   {"Imperial", "SI"}];
```

EDIT: As [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) pointed out in a comment, this can be written more compactly as

```
quantityWithAppropriatePrefix[quant_Quantity] := 
  Fold[UnitConvert, quant, {"Imperial", "SI"}];

quantityWithAppropriatePrefix /@
 {Quantity[0.0000011, "Meter"],
  Quantity[0.0000033, "Feet"]}
```

> {Quantity[1.1, "Micrometers"], Quantity[1.00584, "Micrometers"]}

A brute force approach:

```
quantityWithAppropriatePrefix[quant_Quantity] :=
 Module[{si = UnitConvert[quant, "SI"], mag,
   log10Mag, multiplier},
  mag = QuantityMagnitude[si];
  log10Mag = Round[Log10[mag], 3];
  multiplier = {"Yocto", "Zepto", "Atto", "Femto",
     "Pico", "Nano", "Micro", "Milli", "", "kilo",
     "Mega", "Giga", "Tera", "Peta", "Exa", "Zetta",
     "Yatta"}[[log10Mag/3 + 9]];
  Quantity[mag 10^-log10Mag, multiplier <> QuantityUnit[si]]];

  quantityWithAppropriatePrefix /@ {Quantity[0.0000011, "Meter"], 
      Quantity[0.0000033, "Feet"]}
```

> {Quantity[1.1, "Micrometers"], Quantity[1.00584, "Micrometers"]}

```
Partition[Table[quantityWithAppropriatePrefix[
    Quantity[1.23*10^n, "Volt"]], {n, -25, 25}],
  6] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't leave a lot of room for improvement but I'll try anyway.  If this is used *a lot* `Switch` is not the best choice as it is slower than other options such as a `Dispatch` table or `Association`, or a simple list extraction using `Part`.  May I edit your answer or shall I post it as my own?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Fell free to post your solution.

Comment: I found that the difference in timing is completely swamped by other factors so it is not worth posting separately.  My proposal is simply:  `multiplier = {"Yocto", "Zepto", "Atto", "Femto", "Pico", "Nano", "Micro", "Milli", "", "kilo", "Mega", "Giga", "Tera", "Peta", "Exa", "Zetta", "Yatta"}[[log10Mag/3 + 9]]`.

Comment: `UnitConvert` is enough, no need to `UnitConvert[ #, #2]&`.

Comment: @Kuba - Thanks, included above.

Comment: I think it is more desirable to get $123mV$  `Quantity[123,"Millivolts"]` than $0.123V$ `Quantity[0.123,"Volts"]`. i.e the magnitude should always be larger than $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Just a variant:

```
qf[u_] := Module[{rng = Range[-24, 24, 3],
   multiplier = {"Yocto", "Zepto", "Atto", "Femto", "Pico", "Nano", 
     "Micro", "Milli", "", "Kilo", "Mega", "Giga", "Tera", "Peta", 
     "Exa", "Zetta", "Yatta"}, v, p}, 
  v = QuantityMagnitude[u];
  p = First@Nearest[rng, Log10[v]];
  Quantity[
   v 10^-p, (p /. Thread[rng -> multiplier]) <> QuantityUnit[u]]
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a brute force solution, but seems to be more robust and does not require an internet connection, that I put together based on the other posts in this thread.

```
AutoSIPrefix[quant_Quantity] := (Module[
    {prefixlist, prefixrules, siunitstring, pfloc, baseunit, 
     basequantity, mag, log10Mag, prefix, newunit},
    prefixlist = 
     "kilo" | "mega" | "giga" | "tera" | "peta" | "exa" | "zetta" | 
      "yotta" | "deci" | "centi" | "milli" | "micro" | "nano" | 
      "pico" | "femto" | "atto" | "zepto" | "yocto";
    prefixrules = {3 -> "Kilo", 6 -> "Mega", 9 -> "Giga", 
      12 -> "Tera", 15 -> "Peta", 18 -> "Exa", 21 -> "Zetta", 
      24 -> "Yotta", -1 -> "Deci", -2 -> "Centi", -3 -> "Milli", -6 ->
        "Micro", -9 -> "Nano", -12 -> "Pico", -15 -> 
       "Femto" - 18 -> "Atto", -21 -> "Zepto", -24 -> "Yocto", 
      0 -> ""};
    siunitstring = QuantityUnit[UnitConvert[quant, "SI"]];
    pfloc = 
     StringPosition[siunitstring, prefixlist, IgnoreCase -> True];
    baseunit = 
     If[Length[pfloc] == 1, 
      Capitalize[StringDrop[siunitstring, pfloc[[1]]]], 
      Capitalize[siunitstring]];
    basequantity = 
     UnitConvert[quant, 
      Capitalize[StringDrop[siunitstring, pfloc[[1]]]]];
    mag = QuantityMagnitude[basequantity];
    log10Mag = Round[Log10[mag], 3];
    prefix = log10Mag /. prefixrules;
    newunit = Capitalize[ prefix <> ToLowerCase[baseunit]];
    UnitConvert[quant, newunit]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @ubpdqn, with some small modifications to accept units with prefixes and avoid magnitudes smaller than 1.

```
NicePrefix[input_Quantity] := Module[
  {
   rng = Range[-24, 24, 3], 
   multiplier = {"Yocto", "Zepto", "Atto", "Femto", "Pico", "Nano", 
     "Micro", "Milli", "", "Kilo", "Mega", "Giga", "Tera", "Peta", 
     "Exa", "Zetta", "Yatta"},
   value, power, baseunit
   },
  baseunit = StringDelete[QuantityUnit[input], multiplier];
  value = QuantityMagnitude[input, Capitalize@baseunit];
  power = Clip[Floor[Log10[value], 3], {-24, 24}];
  Quantity[
   value Power[10, -power], (power /. Thread[rng -> multiplier]) <> baseunit]
  ]
```